# Adding a link to download JPGraph bar graph as JPG?

Tags: php, jpgraph

I have an application that uses jpgraph. I would like to be able to give the user the ability to download the graph as a jpg file from a link. Currently the URL looks like so:

```
 chart.php?act=img&t=cost&fy=2012&rt=Electricity&mo=ALL
```

If i right click to download, it will show **"untitled"** as the name and allow me only **.bmp** format. It does show correctly if I preview the image, but I would like to have it save as a **.jpg**

I have looked through the JPGRAPH documentation, but cannot find anything on adding an extension to the generated image.

Anyone have experience doing this or have an idea for me to try?

EDIT:::::

**I have tried to save it to a file, however I have many different graphs and need separate names for each... working on that now....:**

```
$graph->Stroke('tmp/myimage.png');
```

Comment: in `jpg-config.inc.php` change `DEFINE('DEFAULT_GFORMAT','bmp')` to `DEFINE('DEFAULT_GFORMAT','jpg')` check http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch05s05.html

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I gave that a shot earlier, but it would not render my graphs in the JPG format. Just blank X where the graph would be. Right now it is set to AUTO. Thanks for the comment / suggestion though!

Comment: Can you specify exact location of tmp folder ? (eg: /home/my/Desktop/tmp)

Comment: @CanGeliş I was able to get the exact location and able to get the file to download into a temp folder. Thanks for the heads up there.

Answer (score 0):

try using this at the top of **chart.php**

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.jpg"');
```

Comment: Hi Can, thanks for the comment. That didn't change anything when trying to save the file.